# Folder name most folder names starts with (excl. ./)

Tags: bash, directory

I've a list of folder and I'd like to know which folder name most folder names starts with.

Given this list of folders:

```
./
./.something
./unrelated
./Target.Dire ctoryName
./Target.Dire ctoryNameOther
./Target.Dire ctoryName.Other
./Target.Dire ctoryName.Stuff
./Target.Dire ctoryName.Stuff.Other
./Unrelated.Dire ctoryName
./Unrelated.Dire ctoryNameStuff
./Unrelated.Dire ctoryName.Stuff
./Unrelated.Dire ctoryName.Other
./More.Unrelated.Dire ctoryName
./More.Unrelated.Dire ctoryName.Other
```

I'd like to get the name of `./Target.Dire ctoryName` (including space).

I've come up with this, but it excludes hidden folders and is very long, and also doesn't do "starts with" but instead does "contains":

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c \
'for arg do find * -maxdepth 0 -type d | grep -wo "$arg"; done' _ \
| sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head  -1 | echo "./$(awk '{print $2}')"
```

---

There could be two different version, one that includes hidden folders and one that excludes them. For my use-case `find * -maxdepth 0 -type d` includes all potential folders.

---

*Why I need the folder name is because a tool I use is unable to figure out the "target/main" directory when used with a specific argument.*

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to accomplish this is pure bash, but the Python script below should work perfectly for all possible folder names. It will also accept a command line argument (described later under **Optional pattern matching argument**).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    folder = subprocess.run(\
        ['find','-mindepth','1','-maxdepth','1','-type','d','-print0'],\
            capture_output=True).stdout[:-1].split(b'\x00')
else:
    folder = subprocess.run(\
        ['find','-mindepth','1','-maxdepth','1','-type','d',\
            '-name',sys.argv[1], '-print0'],\
            capture_output=True).stdout[:-1].split(b'\x00')
counts = []
for name in folder:
    counts.append(sum(name in i[:len(name)] for i in folder))
counts = sorted(list(zip(counts,folder)),reverse=True)
if counts[0][0]>1:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(counts[0][1]+b'\x0a')
```

Save the script (e.g. as `mainfoldername.py` or whatever) and the command `python3 /path/to/mainfoldername.py` will output the folder name that meets the criteria of occuring most often as the starting string in folder names in the current working directory. If no folders meet that criteria, the script produces no output.

With the example directories you've given, `python3 /path/to/mainfoldername.py` will output **`./Target.Dire ctoryName`**.

Using **command expansion**, a variable can be set to the script's output value and used in other commands:

```
$ myvar="$( python3 /path/to/mainfoldername.py )"
$ echo "$myvar"
./Target.Dire ctoryName
$ cd "$myvar"
Target.Dire ctoryName$
```

### Shell script usage

In **shell scripts** that will use this output, a check for cases where no folder names met the criteria (i.e. the python script produced no output) should be included by testing the value for zero length, e.g:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
myvar="$( python3 /path/to/mainfoldername.py )"
[ ! -z "$myvar" ] || exit 1
```

### Optional pattern matching argument

`python3 /path/to/mainfolder.py PATTERN`

This script will accept one optional argument on the command line where *`PATTERN`* is a shell pattern that folder names must match.

The most basic use of this is as a switch between finding regular folders or finding hidden folders. The script's default behavior is to find all folders.

**To find only hidden folders**, use **`'.*'`** for *`PATTERN`*:

```
python3 /path/to/mainfolder.py '.*'
```

**To find only non-hidden folders**, use **`'[!\.]*'`**

```
python3 /path/to/mainfolder.py '[!\.]*'
```

It's also useful when you know some string that will appear in the target folder's name.

**To find only folders whose names contain the string `Target`**:

```
python3 /path/to/mainfolder.py '*Target*'
```

Note that the patterns should always be contained in quotes to avoid expansion by the shell. See ["Shell Pattern Matching"](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Shell-Pattern-Matching.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question to include dots, spaces, and also capitalised characters so that it might cover most real-world cases.

Comment: I understand now - we want the directory whose name occurs most often as the leading substring in other directory names. I should have paid more attention to the question title lol. Anyway, revised answer should work.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True. I've now revised the script to compare only bytestrings instead of text, then print the resulting bytestring in the systems default encoding. It should be pretty robust now.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think it will work now. Not sure what the correct way is to display such characters, `ls` shows `'foo'$'\200''bar'`, `find` shows `foo?bar1` and my script now shows `foo\x80bar`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's a good point and makes a lot more sense than my attempts to convert the data inside Python. I've changed the script to send the raw directory name to stdout via `sys.stdout.buffer.write()`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, it does look better with a newline.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, you could do something like:

```
all=(*(N/)) max=0 best=
for dir ($all) (){ (( $# > max )) && max=$# best=$dir; } ${(M)all:#$dir*}
print -r -- $max $best
```

Where `*(N/)` expands to the non-hidden files of type *directory* in the current directory (or nothing if there's no match with the `N`ullglob qualifier).

`${(M)all:#$dir*}` expands to the elements of the `$all` array that `M`atch the `$dir*` pattern, that is that start with `$dir`. Those are passed as arguments to an anonymous function (`(){....}`) that compares it to the maximum.

In case of ties, it's the first directory in the list of directories ordered lexically that is selected (replace `>` with `>=` to get the last).

Add the `D` (for `dotglob`) glob qualifier (`all=(*(ND/))`) to include hidden directories (`.` and `..` are always excluded).

---

Below is my original answer where I had read the requirements too quickly. This one finds the common prefix to those directories that is the most common, even if it's not the name of a directory itself. For instance, among `ab1`, `ab2` `ab3`, `bc` and `bc1`, it would return `ab` instead of `bc`:

```
typeset -A c
for f (*(/)) for ((i=1;i<=$#f;i++)) ((c[\$f[1,i]]++))
printf -v argv '%2$08d%1$s' ${(kv)c}
print -r -- ${${(O)@}[1][9,-1]}
```

Where `*(/)` expands to the non-hidden files of type *directory* in the current directory (and aborts with an error if there's none).

Then we build the `$c` associative array that records the occurrences of each possible prefix of those directory names.

Then we construct the `$argv` (aka `$@`) array from the number of occurrences zero-padded to 8 digits followed by the prefix for each of the prefixes.

Then we `O`rder that array in reverse lexically so the first one is the one with the highest number of occurrence, and if there are ties, the one that sorts last (which would also give the longest prefix).

Then we pick the first (`[1]`), and print the 9th to last character (`[9,-1]`) of it.

To include hidden directories, replace `*(/)` with `*(D/)` (adding the `D` for `dotglob` qualifier). `.` and `..` are never included.

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` program would output the directory path that occurs most often as a prefix in all the directory paths in the input.

It is assumed that the directory paths are presented a line at a time and that no pathname contains embedded newlines.

```c
{ sub("/$",""); count[$0] = 0 }

END {
        for (p1 in count)
                for (p2 in count) {
                        count[p2] += (index(p1,p2) == 1)
                        if (count[p2] > m) {
                                m = count[p2]
                                p = p2
                        }
                }

        print p
}
```

This reads each line of input and stores them as keys in the associative array `count`.  Any trailing `/` is first removed.

When all input has been read, the stored keys are compared in pairs, and the number of times each occur as a substring in another is counted.  We keep track of the pathname that has occurred the most times in `p`, and the number of time it has occurred in `m`.

The call `index(p1,p2)` returns the position in the string `p1` where `p2` occurs (or zero if it does not occur at all), and we're only interested in the cases where this results in the number 1 (`p2` occurs at the start of `p1`).

The above program could also be written in-line on the command line as follows:

```bsh
awk '{ sub("/$",""); c[$0]=0 } END { for (a in c) for (b in c) { c[b]+=(index(a,b)==1); if (c[b]>m) { m=c[b]; p=b } } print p }'
```

As input to this, you could possibly use

```bsh
printf '%s\n' ./*/
```

(with `dotglob` enabled in the `bash` shell to also get hidden directory names.)

In the end, you'll get something like

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob
printf '%s\n' ./*/ | awk -f script
```

(or use the longer in-line `awk` script in place of `-f script`.)

Testing:

```bsh
$ ls -FA
.something/                                   Unrelated.Dire ctoryName/
Target.Dire ctoryName/                        Unrelated.Dire ctoryName.Other/
Target.Dire ctoryName.Other/                  Unrelated.Dire ctoryName.Stuff/
Target.Dire ctoryName.Stuff/                  Unrelated.Dire ctoryNameStuff/
Target.Dire ctoryName.Stuff.Other/            script
Target.Dire ctoryNameOther/                   unrelated/
```

```bsh
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ printf '%s\n' ./*/ | awk -f script
./Target.Dire ctoryName
```

Answer (score 0):

## F# Script

Using an F# Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/dotnet fsi
let dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(".")
printfn"%s" (dirs |> Array.maxBy (fun d -> dirs |> (Array.filter (fun d' -> d'.StartsWith(d)) >> Array.length)))
```

In the directory, run `dotnet fsi /path/to/mainfoldername.fsx`.

Answer (score -1):

## C# Script

Here's a [C# Script](https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env dotnet-script
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(".");
Console.Write(dirs.MaxBy(d => dirs.Count(x => x.StartsWith(d))));
```

In the directory, run `dotnet script /path/to/mainfoldername.csx`.

Comment: Unlike C#, Python is already included on practically every Linux distribution. Not sure why it wouldn't be "allowed". Since you are the question asker, it would be much more productive if you commented on answers already given and explained why they are unacceptable.

Comment: The GitHub Action runners (where I needed to find the folder) have [.NET pre-installed](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md#net-core-sdk).